# How to insert numbers in words for the numeric value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, triggers, user-defined-functions

I want to edit this code for SQL Server.

For example, when I enter "2500$" price it should be automatically insert in the next field as "Only two thousand five hundred dollars". Additionally when I enter 100.35 it should automatically insert other field as " Only one hundred dollars and thirty-five cents".

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Currency_ToWords] (
    @Input Numeric (38) -- Input number with as many as 18 digits

) RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) 

/*
* Converts a integer number as large as 34 digits into the 
* equivalent words.  The first letter is capitalized.
*
* Attribution: Based on NumberToWords by Srinivas Sampath
*        as revised by Nick Barclay
*
* Example:
select dbo.udf_Num_ToWords (1234567890) + CHAR(10)
      +  dbo.udf_Num_ToWords (0) + CHAR(10)
      +  dbo.udf_Num_ToWords (123) + CHAR(10)
select dbo.udf_Num_ToWords(76543210987654321098765432109876543210)

DECLARE @i numeric (38,0)
SET @i = 0
WHILE @I <= 1000 BEGIN 
    PRINT convert (char(5), @i)  
            + convert(varchar(255), dbo.udf_Num_ToWords(@i)) 
    SET @I  = @i + 1 
END
*
* Published as the T-SQL UDF of the Week Vol 2 #9 2/17/03
****************************************************************/
AS BEGIN
Declare @Number Numeric(38,0)
set @Number = @Input
Declare @Cents as int
set @Cents = 100*Convert(money,(@Input - convert(Numeric(38,3),@Number)))
DECLARE @inputNumber VARCHAR(38)
DECLARE @NumbersTable TABLE (number CHAR(2), word VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @outputString VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @length INT
DECLARE @counter INT
DECLARE @loops INT
DECLARE @position INT
DECLARE @chunk CHAR(3) -- for chunks of 3 numbers
DECLARE @tensones CHAR(2)
DECLARE @hundreds CHAR(1)
DECLARE @tens CHAR(1)
DECLARE @ones CHAR(1)

IF @Number = 0 Return 'Zero'

-- initialize the variables
SELECT @inputNumber = CONVERT(varchar(38), @Number)
     , @outputString = ''
     , @counter = 1
SELECT @length   = LEN(@inputNumber)
     , @position = LEN(@inputNumber) - 2
     , @loops    = LEN(@inputNumber)/3

-- make sure there is an extra loop added for the remaining numbers
IF LEN(@inputNumber) % 3 <> 0 SET @loops = @loops + 1

-- insert data for the numbers and words
INSERT INTO @NumbersTable   SELECT '00', ''
    UNION ALL SELECT '01', 'one'      UNION ALL SELECT '02', 'two'
    UNION ALL SELECT '03', 'three'    UNION ALL SELECT '04', 'four'
    UNION ALL SELECT '05', 'five'     UNION ALL SELECT '06', 'six'
    UNION ALL SELECT '07', 'seven'    UNION ALL SELECT '08', 'eight'
    UNION ALL SELECT '09', 'nine'     UNION ALL SELECT '10', 'ten'
    UNION ALL SELECT '11', 'eleven'   UNION ALL SELECT '12', 'twelve'
    UNION ALL SELECT '13', 'thirteen' UNION ALL SELECT '14', 'fourteen'
    UNION ALL SELECT '15', 'fifteen'  UNION ALL SELECT '16', 'sixteen'
    UNION ALL SELECT '17', 'seventeen' UNION ALL SELECT '18', 'eighteen'
    UNION ALL SELECT '19', 'nineteen' UNION ALL SELECT '20', 'twenty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '30', 'thirty'   UNION ALL SELECT '40', 'forty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '50', 'fifty'    UNION ALL SELECT '60', 'sixty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '70', 'seventy'  UNION ALL SELECT '80', 'eighty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '90', 'ninety'   

WHILE @counter <= @loops BEGIN

    -- get chunks of 3 numbers at a time, padded with leading zeros
    SET @chunk = RIGHT('000' + SUBSTRING(@inputNumber, @position, 3), 3)

    IF @chunk <> '000' BEGIN
        SELECT @tensones = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 2, 2)
             , @hundreds = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 1, 1)
             , @tens = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 2, 1)
             , @ones = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 3, 1)

        -- If twenty or less, use the word directly from @NumbersTable
        IF CONVERT(INT, @tensones) <= 20 OR @Ones='0' BEGIN
            SET @outputString = (SELECT word 
                                      FROM @NumbersTable 
                                      WHERE @tensones = number)
                   + CASE @counter WHEN 1 THEN '' -- No name
                       WHEN 2 THEN ' thousand ' WHEN 3 THEN ' million '
                       WHEN 4 THEN ' billion '  WHEN 5 THEN ' trillion '
                       WHEN 6 THEN ' quadrillion ' WHEN 7 THEN ' quintillion '
                       WHEN 8 THEN ' sextillion '  WHEN 9 THEN ' septillion '
                       WHEN 10 THEN ' octillion '  WHEN 11 THEN ' nonillion '
                       WHEN 12 THEN ' decillion '  WHEN 13 THEN ' undecillion '
                       ELSE '' END
                               + @outputString
            END
         ELSE BEGIN -- break down the ones and the tens separately

             SET @outputString = ' ' 
                            + (SELECT word 
                                    FROM @NumbersTable 
                                    WHERE @tens + '0' = number)
                             + '-'
                             + (SELECT word 
                                    FROM @NumbersTable 
                                    WHERE '0'+ @ones = number)
                   + CASE @counter WHEN 1 THEN '' -- No name
                       WHEN 2 THEN ' thousand ' WHEN 3 THEN ' million '
                       WHEN 4 THEN ' billion '  WHEN 5 THEN ' trillion '
                       WHEN 6 THEN ' quadrillion ' WHEN 7 THEN ' quintillion '
                       WHEN 8 THEN ' sextillion '  WHEN 9 THEN ' septillion '
                       WHEN 10 THEN ' octillion '  WHEN 11 THEN ' nonillion '
                       WHEN 12 THEN ' decillion '   WHEN 13 THEN ' undecillion '
                       ELSE '' END
                            + @outputString
        END

        -- now get the hundreds
        IF @hundreds <> '0' BEGIN
            SET @outputString  = (SELECT word 
                                      FROM @NumbersTable 
                                      WHERE '0' + @hundreds = number)
                                + ' hundred ' 
                                + @outputString
        END
    END

    SELECT @counter = @counter + 1
         , @position = @position - 3

END

-- Remove any double spaces
SET @outputString = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@outputString, '  ', ' ')))
SET @outputstring = UPPER(LEFT(@outputstring, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@outputstring, 2, 8000)


RETURN UPPER(@outputString)   -- return the result
END
```

and I need trigger code for call this function automatically.

Thanks

Comment: We don't write code for you. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Is it possible in sql server pls guide with explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @user3334756 It is possible. You function is a good start. You shoud rewrite it as it is rounding the numbers. For exmaple `SELECT [dbo].[Currency_ToWords] (100.54)` will give you `ONE HUNDRED ONE`.

Comment: 2nd post by this user today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428355/converting-currency-numeric-field-into-words-dollars-and-cents-using-triggers

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand it is not duplicated as he need improvement to be done

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i need to write directly. Because numbers are total price. when I enter 100.35 it should automatically insert other field as " Only one hundred dollars and thirty-five cents".

Comment: @gotqn So, you take the answer there and build on it. We don't need a new solution for every single possible variation of this problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree that they are hundreds of duplicated questions and using the answer there is a good starting point. Anyway, this could consume two minutes of yours, ten minutes of mine, two hours of someone else... having different version of the function could save time.

Comment: @gotqn I disagree. Shouldn't some of the work be on the OP? After all, they're the one with the problem. I don't think every time someone invents some variation on this, a bunch of people should start brand new answers that do *almost exactly the same thing* as the duplicate. This is the whole reason we have duplicates in the first place: to avoid duplication of effort on the part of the answerers.

Comment: @AaronBertrand you are completely right. On the other hand, `duplicate` means `a copy exactly like an original`. So, as in this case (and many others), `duplicated` does not sound like the appropriate question state for me.

Comment: @gotqn I think that your interpretation is too literal. I mean, if someone asks the exact same question but with an extra comma, or another space, or anything it won't be an exact copy but it's still a duplicate. And in this case, the question is clearly a duplicate, it just needs a little work

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_get_Only_Numbers
 (
   @var nvarchar(max)
 )
 RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Number DECIMAL(10,2);
    SELECT  @Number =  LEFT(Val,PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', Val+'a')-1) 
    from(SELECT SUBSTRING(@var, PATINDEX('%[0-9.]%', @var), LEN(@var)) Val)x
  RETURN @Number;
END
```

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(Value VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
('Balance100.50sheet'), ('Value100'),('50 dollars'),('100$')
```

### Query

```
SELECT dbo.fn_get_Only_Numbers(Value)
FROM @TABLE
```

### Result

```
100.50
100.00
50.00
100.00
```

Comment: He wants the numeric value `100.50` to be converted to the string `'One hundred dollars and fifty cents.'`. I don't think this does that.

Comment: oh Alright, I thought op only wanted integer values from values like `2500$` or `50.15 dollars`  :S all this effort for nothing, Should I delete it?